# Highlight a row in excel if any column in that row is greater than 0

Tags: excel, row, highlight, conditional-formatting

This is my first post and I've been searching forever but need some help.

I have a spreadsheet that contains Stock Codes in column A for 153 rows (A2:A153) and dates in columns F through BL that list the quantity for each Stock so, for example, it looks like this linked image:

[image: spreadsheet]

The issue is that there are a ton of rows that have Quantities of just 0, I want to use conditional formatting to highlight ANY row that contains a number greater than 0 in ANY of its columns.

So for example if Row 5 has a 7 in Z5, even if every other column is 0, then the entire row highlights green.

Likewise, if every column for Row 5 (A-BL) is 0 then it doesn't highlighted.

I thought this would be easy but I'm struggling so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: cfr based on `=countif($b1:$bl1, ">0")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you'll need to do:

- Select cell A1
- Click "Conditional Formatting" -> "New rule"
- "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- Type the formula =COUNTIF(1:1, ">0")
- Choose the formatting you want
- Click OK, then go to "Conditional Formatting" -> "Manage Rules"
- Change the area your rule applies to so that it fits whatever rows you want (ex 1:1000)

[Here's a GIF showing the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq7r4.jpg)

**EDIT:** To get the rule to include negative numbers, just change the formula to =OR(COUNTIF(1:1,">0"),COUNTIF(1:1,"<0"))

If you played with multiple rules and tweaked them a bit you could even get the row to highlight red if the average of all numbers in the row is negative and green if it's positive.

Comment: Wouldn't `COUNTIF(1:1, "<>0")` be the same as `OR(COUNTIF(1:1, ">0"), COUNTIF(1:1, "<0"))`?

Comment: @Jeeped That would work, but only if there were also no blank fields, as a blank field is not the same as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=IF(OR(COUNTIF($A1:$D1,"<0")>0,SUM($A1:$D1)=0),FALSE,TRUE)`

[image]

Comment: There we go, I think I got it!

Comment: mmm, I don't remember the rule with the `-1`